# Japanese characters insert into MYSQL DB with Django returns 500 error

Tags: mysql, django, encoding

On my Django website I can't insert from the auto generated admin dashboard any Japanese or Chinese characters, it returns a 500 error.

Here is my my.cnf config :

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

the database is encoded in utf8 (COLLATE utf8_general_ci)

What could cause this bug?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm just getting a "Server Error (500)", also I can insert Japanese/Chinese characters in this same DB with a standalone python script connecting this way : conn = MySQLdb.connect(servername, username, password,
                       dbname, charset='utf8', init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')

cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute("SET NAMES UTF8;")

Comment: There must be a traceback in your logs somewhere?

Comment: But on Django I'm stuck with this 500 error

Comment: I just checked but there is nothing into mysql error logs

Comment: The Django logs?

Comment: could you show us your could if you connected with utf8 and used prepared statements with parameters

Comment: The problem with your question is that http error code 500 simply means "something has gone wrong in the server", but does not provide any details. You need to identify the underlying error (python or mysql) that triggers the error message. Until then, we can only guess.

Comment: here is how I connect to the db:     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
            'init_command': 'SET names=utf8,character_set_connection=utf8,collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci',
            'charset': 'utf8',
        }
    }

Comment: Can you run Django from the commandline?  That might not hide the errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the app model I removed this:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

(title was the field I was trying to edit); and it's now working
I'm still trying to figure what causes this problem and how to fix.